# mysql like performance boost

Tags: mysql, sql-like

is there anyway to speed up mysql like operator performance if wild card is involved? eg. like '%test%'

Answer (score 27, accepted):

MySQL can use an index if your query looks like `foo LIKE 'abc%'` or `foo LIKE 'abc%def%'`. It can use the index for any portion or the string before the first wildcard. If you need to match a word anywhere within a string, you might want to consider using `FULLTEXT` indexes instead.

More detail on indexes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html

Full text search: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: essentially, if you index a column with B+ Tree index, that's sufficient. Automatically MySql searches faster for LIKE queries

Answer (score 5):

Well, the simplest optimization would be to have a constant prefix (e.g. `"test%"` instead of `"%test"` or `"%test%"`) since that would allow the engine to narrow down the search space using indices. However, that is not possible in all situations.

Sometimes a preprocessing step can turn a wildcard search into an ordinary equality or a fulltext search. You'll gain more by finding a way to structure your data so that it does not require a wildcard search than trying to optimize the latter.