# Cache and speed up solution for like-statement

Tags: mysql, caching, sql-like

I faced with MySql query which takes too much CPU and time to execute

The query is looks like

**Select * from table where table.a LIKE %a% OR table.a LIKE %b% OR table.a LIKE %c%**

We do need this LIKE statements, due to business requirements (we need to look for any equalities).

So how it is possible to speed it up?
Is there any caches we could use? Is there some NoSql solutions would be good?
I suppose that even if we load all table to memory we still will have poor performance due to full-text scans because of these LIKEs.

Will it be better if we use regexp there?
What approaches are typically good for such text-search purposes?
If we switch to NoSql, will it be better? 
What particular product can help us?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql like performance boost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481528/mysql-like-performance-boost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that wildcarded searches can't make very efficient use of indexes, hence your performance issues. RegEx will be no better, in fact it will probably be worse.

I'd suggest setting up a [fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) on that field if the reason you are using wildcards is to pick out individual words from a textual field. It will allow you to do searches without wildcards for individual words. However, it won't help much if you are searching on parts of words like your example %b%.

Switching to NoSQL because of a few queries performing poorly seems like extreme overkill, and I doubt it would help enough to justify it for that reason alone.

Comment: the problem is we are searching thru the user nicknames, so there could not be tokens extracted and indexed. Is there any caching solutions which  might helps?

Comment: Caching might work, but only if you knew the search terms people were going to use in advance or if people searched on the same terms frequently.

Comment: Could you please suggest any caching solution? Or we can just use plain mysql query cache?

Comment: I don't think you are understanding my point. Caching won't likely help you. Do you know the search terms in advance people will use?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding
Well, the table consists only of two columns, that is username and user_vcard, the like statement is searching thru the vcards and the query returns list of usernames. We probably could gather some statistic of searches, but I'm not sure that we can say that we aware of the terms people use.

Comment: Then caching probably won't help. You do understand that caching is really just pre-running and saving the results of commonly run, expensive queries. Right?