# How do i perform a search in mysql with a substring, instead of full string?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search, substring

How do i perform a search in mysql with a substring, instead of full string ?

i would like to return information from a search term e.g.. 'Wat' will return Waterloo and any other words with Wat in them ..

Comment: Did you manage to accomplish what you wanted?

Comment: yes i did.. just realize i am responding to this really late! :/ @FilipeSilva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *like '%Wat%'*, but if you want more sophisticated conditions, you may consider using *rlike* which leverages regular expressions

Comment: @KarimKawambwa you are welcome. Be careful though that searching using `like` does have an impact on performance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481528/mysql-like-performance-boost

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a like:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE YOURCOLUMN LIKE '%Wat%';
```

If you are only looking for something starting with Wat you can drop the first %