# mysql fulltext index performance issue

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table with different fields, in particular name (varchar 255), surname (varchar 255), but actually I used them as name (varchar 90) and surname (varchar 70), considering the maxlength limit.

This table has ~620,000 rows and I'm doing a lot of queries like the following one:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%word1%" AND surname LIKE "%word2%"
```

I've added FULLTEXT indexes on both field (tried also one index contains both fields), but the performance is slower than queries without any index.

What I missing?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Following your replies, I show you some results.

Case A. 
Table without any index
Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE  `name` LIKE '%word1%'
AND  `surname` LIKE '%word2%'
```

executed two times was solved in 0.8870 and 0.8952 sec

Case B.
I've added a FULLTEXT index on name and a FULLTEXT index on surname.
Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE match(name) AGAINST ('+word1*' in boolean mode) 
AND match(surname) AGAINST ('+word2*' in boolean mode)
```

executed two times was solved in 0.9647 and 1.0380 sec

Note: table has InnoDB engine and unfortunatly MySQL is older than 5.6; I cannot convert easily from InnoDB to MyISAM because of foreign keys.

Other ideas?
Thanks again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql like performance boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481528/mysql-like-performance-boost)

Comment: `LIKE '%pattern%` can't use indexes.

Comment: It is basically the same question, yes. Why is slower?

Comment: Of course, `FULLTEXT` indexes don't help make `LIKE '%match%'` WHERE clauses faster. You have to use `FULLTEXT` style WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 3):

It will be better if you use Mysql (InnoDB)'s Full text search in boolean mode.
More Details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html)

Fulltext search is designed to be efficient in cases like yours and is considerably faster than full scan.

A fulltext search query for your case might look like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE match(name) against ('+word1*' in boolean mode) AND match(surname) against ('+word2*' in boolean mode);
```

Comment: You should be atleast be using MySQL 5.6 or up before this can work for the InnoDB engine, InnoDB engine in lower MySQL versions will not support FULL TEXT indexes.. If you have a lower MySQL version MyISAM engine can also handle FULL TEXT indexes.

Comment: I've edited my first post. FULLTEXT index, not FULLSCAN index. Sorry for my error.

Comment: agreed @RaymondNijland. The answer assumes this limitation. Thanks for clarifying the MyISAM engine details though :)

Comment: @qweqwe please run the `match against` query and please update if the performance improves.

Comment: Just do it on the first post

Answer (score 1):

"cannot convert easily" -- Sure you can.  Make a MyISAM table with nothing but the text column(s) and the id.  Then do the `MATCH..AGAINST` using that table and `JOIN` (without FKs) to the InnoDB table.  The `id` is already the `PRIMARY KEY` of the other table, correct?  The `JOIN` just needs an index; the PK qualifies as such; no FK is required.

You do have a 2-column `FULLTEXT` index, correct?  `FULLTEXT(name, surname)`