# select where start from first not substr mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to make a research but just from prefixe.

Eg. when I search `10542`, `110542` shouldn't be there, just `105428001`.

The string :

```
110542004
105428001
```

I tried

```
LEFT(INV.INV_CD,5) LIKE '%".$option3."%'";
```

and

```
SUBSTRING(INV.INV_CD,1,5) LIKE '%".$option3."%'";
```

Both result are the same.

Comment: Your first % in the like allows it to start anywhere, remove it to start at the beginning.

Comment: Note that with `%` at the start of your string, the optimizer can't use the index on that column *if any* [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481528/mysql-like-performance-boost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a % in your like clause, this allows any characters, so one at the begining allows it to start anywhere.  Remove it to start at the begning...

```
INV.INV_CD LIKE '".$option3."%'";
```

**Note:** You should also try to use prepared statements as they can stop a lot of problems in the future!

Comment: but when i write 105, i get nothing. that's why i make it %

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, do you mean that `$option3` is 105?

Comment: ouh sory i'm wrong. i think it because %. but remove in begning. thanks nigel. sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `LIKE` syntax :

```
LIKE '%".$option3."%'";
```

When you use `%` it means you can have something at the same place, so `LIKE '%".$option3."%'";` you can return value with `XXXX + $option3 + XXXX` (with `XXXX` equal to nothing or multiple char)

If you only want `$option3 + XXXX`, just write `LIKE '".$option3."%'";`

Here is the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) about this :

> With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern:
>
> % matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
>
> _ matches exactly one character.

Comment: Well you have a problem somewhere, but if you have `105428001` and you write your query with `LIKE '105%'` you will return it : here is an example http://sqlfiddle.com/index.html#!9/f0386e/1